# Combinatorial packages of N items [[How many distinct Boolean Expressions can be made using N variables]]

Tags: combinatorics, logic, combinations

Using just the AND operator, the number of distinct packages that can be built from a set of size $n$, is simply $2^n$. If one adds the operators OR and XOR, how many packages can be built? That is, with a set of cardinality 1, we just have 2 (the empty set and the whole set). With a set of size two, we have the empty set, the two singletons, and the three paired--one for each operator. As we go to a set of size three, I'm concerned about how associativity might affect things (A OR (B XOR C)) is different from ((A OR B) XOR C) for example. Is there a way in general to count how many distinct packages there are?

For background, I'm concerned about combinatorial auctions using a very expressive language which permits building packages using these three boolean operators. Obviously the growth is exponential, but I'm hoping for a more precise figure or hints on how this could be calculated.

If parentheses weren't a problem, it seems like it would be $(n,0)+(n,1)+(n,2)*3+(n,3)*3^2+\ldots (n,n)*3^{(n-1)}$ where $(n,k)$ is the binomial coefficient. This is a lower bound because a) it doesn't include parentheses and b) it doesn't consider how the items are ordered and c) I think once you go to packages of size three, items may need to appear in the expression multiple times.

So yes, I'm quite lost on how to incorporate all this stuff.

Many thanks!

EDIT:
Perhaps this could be rephrased as "How many distinct Boolean expressions can be made using N variables and the operators AND OR and XOR?" I am not 100% those two questions are the same.

Edit 2:
I think the answer is bound above by $2^{2^N}$ since that is the number of boolean functions on $N$ boolean variables.

Comment: In case you are interested, you can format multiplication, e.g. $a\cdot b$ by using `a \cdot b`. In any event, thank you for taking time to format your question, adding context, clarification, etc. (+1)

Comment: Interesting question; I don't know the answer. You might find clues in work on normal forms in propositional logic. Wikipedia has an article at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form